# Configuring Memcached Log Location in RHEL7

Tags: logging, memcached, rhel7

I have been searching in here for a while and tried the suggestions provided by experts. My memcache is not writing log in the specified location mentioned in /etc/sysconfig/memcached. Configuration is given below.

But as suggested in [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/208538/how-to-specify-the-log-file-for-memcached-on-rhel-centos) question, when I apply the below command it starts writing log in /tmp/memcached.log. In that scenario, only the start and stops are written and -vv is not in action. Can anyone help me out what am I missing?

Note: I dont have /etc/memcached.conf file in my installation and OS is RHEL7.4.

[Image with issuing command from the other stack post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPCV9.jpg)

/etc/sysconfig/memcached:

```
PORT="11211"
USER="root"
MAXCONN="20000"
CACHESIZE="6000"
MAXITEMSIZE="128m"
LOGFILE="/tmp/memcached.log"
OPTIONS="-vv>>/tmp/memcached.log 2>&1"
```